# Function to get currently executing directory name of executing file

Tags: php

How to get the currently executing directory of the currently executing file? This needs to return the currently executing file's directory even if the file is included by another file. I landed on this:

```
$dir =  str_replace(basename(__FILE__),"",__FILE__);
```

But is there a more straightforward way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the directory of the file I use the dirname function like this :

```
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);
```